# Android:drag and drop items from one list to another

Tags: android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-listview, android

I am looking for a nice user interface where i can move files from one folder(in phone memory) to another(cloud storage space) using drag and drop..

Can i represent files in my folders as a listView?drag and drop in it?

Can anybody help me with a sample or point me in the right direction or give any info thing regarding this...

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just know that official DnD api only introduced in 3.0 so a DnD code will be long and a little complicated but it shouldn't be too hard because it has already been done many times just use a sample you can find - I would use google's music app sort code or @CommonsWare [code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist) which is based on it and tweak it to your liking around the drop code (remove the reappearing in a new location and add your code for moving it to a new location).

I hope it helps and good luck!